# Change CSV function from Int to Array

Tags: powershell, csv

I haven't quite figured out how to change my function which uses an integer as input, into one that can accept an array of inputs. The aim is to change some cells in a CSV at cell nummer (input). I would like to enable the function to change an array of cellnumbers at once.

Here's what I got:

```
function Verander-Data {
    Param($User)
    $csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Deep Dive Windows PowerShell\KolomToegevoegd.csv' -Delimiter ";"
    $currentDate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
    foreach ($row in $csv) {
        if ($row.klantnummer -eq $user) { $row.status = "Verleden" } 
        if ($row.klantnummer -eq $user) { $row.uitgangsdatum = $currentDate }
    }
    $csv | Export-Csv 'C:\Deep Dive Windows PowerShell\Verander-Data.csv' -Delimiter ";"  
}

Verander-Data -User(11)
```

Here's a sample of the CSV:

```
Klantnummer Nationaliteit   Geslacht    Title   Voornaam    MiddleInitial
1   Dutch   female  Ms. Josanne S
2   Dutch   female  Mrs.    Inci    K
3   Dutch   female  Mrs.    Lusanne G
4   Dutch   female  Dr. Husna   M
```

Comment: Strange, to me it looks like the 2nd question but under a new account https://stackoverflow.com/users/9924242/max-kwaasteniet with a score of -4 and this +4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-contains` operator here. You can pass an array of Ids to the function, then as you iterate over the csv, check if the array contains the current `$row.klantnummer`:

```
Function Verander-Data
{
  Param($User)
  $csv = Import-Csv 'C:\Deep Dive Windows PowerShell\KolomToegevoegd.csv' -Delimiter ";"
  $currentDate = Get-Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd
  foreach ($row in $csv) {
    if ($user -contains $row.klantnummer) { 
      $row.status = "Verleden" 
      $row.uitgangsdatum = $currentDate 
    }
  }
  $csv | Export-Csv 'C:\Deep Dive Windows PowerShell\Verander-Data.csv' -Delimiter ";"  
}

Verander-Data -User 10
Verander-Data -User 11,15,19
```

The `-contains` operator will work if you pass a single or multipe Ids

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! I upvoted your answer, is there anything else I can do to express my gratitude?

Comment: @Max, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for what to do when your question was answered. If you feel this was the most useful answer and it solved your problem you can **accept** it by clicking the check mark